# Can Sombra hack Bastion out of his ult?

Tags: overwatch

I know that Sombra can hack Bastion when he's in turret mode and it will change him back to sentry mode, but what happens if he's in tank mode for his ult?  Does it make a difference if Sombra uses her ult compared to her normal hack ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bastion will stay in his ultimate tank mode until the timer on that runs out or he's killed (or some other character's ability is used that can bring him out of tank mode).  It doesn't matter if Sombra uses her hack ability or her ultimate.  I tested this with a friend in a custom match after seeing a PotG of Bastion ulting, followed by an enemy Sombra ulting to try and shut him down.  It didn't go so well for the Sombra.

Comment: PS: I think it's BS that Sombra can't hack an ulting Bastion back to sentry mode.  How is it any different from changing him from turret to sentry?

Comment: Hacking does not normally revert characters from a transformed state to their natural state; it just stops them from using abilities to switch states. Hacking Bastion out of turret form is actually doing Bastion a favour because it means he isn't locked immobile for the hack's duration. I'm guessing this was highly unfun for the playtesters so they added it as a special case.

Comment: It's annoying that Sombra's hack doesn't stop *an electrical visor that targets everyone* but forces a fat man to *take a mechanical piece off his gun to stop it from auto-firing*

Comment: What gets interrupted seems to have more to do with how the ability being interrupted is coded than what makes logical sense. Channeled abilities (Like Roadhog ult) can be interrupted by CC, whereas transformation abilities (Soilder76/Genji Ult) aren't. Bastion getting hacked from turret to sentry seems to be the exception rather than the rule, especially since other CC (Flashbang, Mei Freeze) doesn't cause him to flip modes.